# Few questions about Group Temporal Key (GTK) in WPA/WPA2

Tags: wpa2

I have a few question about group key in WPA family:

**1. How many bits GTK have?** How much characters this key have?

**2. From which characters GTK can be generated?** From 0-9, a-z etc.?

**3. Is GTK the final key to encrypt packets (GTK encrypts packets directly?)?**

**4. If not, what key encrypts multicast traffic? Which formula describes this key derivation from GTK?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1**. GTK has 128 bits for CCMP and 256 bits for TKIP

**2**. Multicast traffic is protected with another key: GTK (Group Transient key), generated from a master key called GMK (Group Master Key) which is a fixed string based on access point MAC address and a random number GNonce.

**3 and 4**. GTK is divided into temporary keys:

- GEK (Group Encryption Key): Key used for data encryption (used by CCMP for auth and by TKIP for encryption).
- GIK (Group Integrity Key): Key used for data auth (used only by Michael for TKIP).

[image: gtp]

Amazing pdf manual about this: [Wi-Fi security – WEP, WPA 
and WPA2](http://tele1.dee.fct.unl.pt/rit2_2015_2016/files/hakin9_wifi_EN.pdf)